# iterate custom fields of object(record) to get string of, label of fields that are checked

Tags: apex, describesobject

Here is what I'm trying to do:

I've a record of custom metadata type object. It has only check box type custom fields(around 10). I want to write a function, which will provide me list of fields which are checked, when I pass one of such record to that function.

This is what I've done and working fine but wondering, if there is shortest way:

```
 // create before-hand map of field name and field details and pass to below function
 private List<string>  findCheckedFields(xyz__mdt record1, Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap ){

     List<string> returnList = new list<string>();

     if(record1.abc__c == true )
        returnList.add(fieldMap.get('abc__c').getDescribe().getLabel());
     if(record1.def__c== true )
        returnList.add(fieldMap.get('def__c').getDescribe().getLabel());
     if(record1.efg__c== true )
       --------- and So on ..................
       -------------------------------
       return returnlist;
     }
```

Problem is, in future, if some new field is added to custom meta data, then I've to modify this method(code) to include check of that field.

I want method, which should be able to check(handle), any new fields added, automatically, without need to modify code.

Comment: I assume that like normal SObjects you can use [describe calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) to get the set of fields and base your logic on that e.g. `for (SObjectField field : xyz__mdt.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) { ... }`.

Comment: Thanks Keith. Before I could proceed myself on this, Sfdcfox has given wonderful solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create a list of fields and access them dynamically:

```
List<string> findCheckedFields(xyz__mdt record1) {
    String[] results = new String[0];
    // Get list of fields dynamically
    for(SObjectField field: xyz__mdt.sobjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
        // We compare any type to true, okay because value must be
        // not-null, a Boolean, and true in order to match.
        if(record1.get(field) == true) {
            results.add(field.getDescribe().getLabel());
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

As a matter of performance, consider bulkifying this code so that the describe is not called repeatedly. One possible solution to this might be:

```
// Store describe information so we initialize only once per transaction.
// We can use SObjectField tokens as keys.
static Map<SObjectField, String> fieldLabels;

List<List<String>> findCheckedFields(xyz__mdt[] records) {
    List<List<String>> results = new List<List<String>>();
    // Lazy-loading: only describe fields once this method is
    // called, and initialize only once.
    if(fieldLabels == null) {
        fieldLabels = new Map<SObjectField, String>();
        for(SObjectField field: xyz__mdt.sobjectType.getDesribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
            fieldLabels.put(field, field.getDescribe().getLabel());
        }
    }
    // For each record
    for(SObject record: records) {
        List<String> recordResults = new List<String>();
        // For each field
        for(SObjectField field: fieldLabels.keySet()) {
            // Compare field value to Boolean true
            if(record.get(field) == true) {
                recordResults.add(fieldLabels.get(field));
            }
        }
        results.add(recordResults);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The final output of this method will be a list of lists of strings, one for each record, with records having no checked fields returning an empty list.